# Powerbuilder 12 classic version Scc option Unavailable

Tags: powerbuilder

I can't perform any of the source control options in powerbuilder classic version 12. They are just greyed out. at startup i get standard message Connection to source control established. objects under pbl shows sign of out of syc. but i can't use option Get Latest Version as its greyed out. we are using Microsoft Team Foundation Server fo Souce control. operating system is Windows 7 32 bit.

Comment: May be smth wrong with permissions on source control server? Try to compare with "PB Native", will it works?

Comment: What does the SCC log (under Workspace properties, Source Control) say?

Comment: @Maximus, permissions are correct on TFS sourc control server. I am able to see scc options enabled in TFS. It is through powerbuilder these options are disabled.

Comment: @Terry, SCC log don't contain any error. it containes date + no of entries read + message saying connection establised successfull.

Comment: Is this a new setup or something that just started happening?

Comment: @HughBrackett, Yes its new setup on windows 7 machine.

Comment: Do you have other computers that source control is working from PB? If so are any Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have this registry key:

HKLM\SOFTWARE\SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders

I've seen some source control tools either not use it, or remove it, and PowerBuilder looks there for the SCC vendors.  If there are none there, then PB won't show the SCC options as available.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check - Make sure the workspace file (*.pbw) is not read-only.  Right click on the file and verify that the *.pbw file does not have the Read-Only attribute checkbox selected.